# Проверка, что запрос к бд успешно выполнен Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Доброе утро, господа.
Если тут кто-то работает на ларавеле, то это вопрос к вам.

Каким образом вы проверяете что запрос к бд (select, insert...) успешно выполнен?

try catch, проверка на true, или может еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: Laravel - это фремворк. То есть код, который написан для того, чтобы выполнять за программиста рутинную работу. В частности, проверять на ошибки. Зачем это делать вручную - загадка.

Answer (score -1):

Зависит все от формата самого запроса. Если при получении данных необходимо проверить, то тут несколько вариантов `$item = $Model->first()` например например можно проверить например `if($item->id)`, а `$items = $Model->get()` уже стоит проверять по к примеру `if(count($items->toArray()))`
Что касается  insert, в случае успеха вернется объект который можно проверить так же `if($item->id)`, a update по моему возвращает 1 если запрос выполнен успешно.

Comment: Это всё не имеет ничего общего с реальностью. В случае ошибки ни один из приведённых здесь методов работать не будет